# JS: How to use await in a loop to play sequential phases of parallel animations with promise.all?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, animation, async-await, es6-promise

**Goal**: Sequentially loop through multiple phases. In each phase, if there are any animations, play all animations in that phase at the same time (*promise.all*). When all animations in the phase are finished (*await the promise of finished*), loop to the next phase.

1. Start loop at phase A, and play all animations in phase A at the same
   time.
2. Then loop to phase B, and play all animations in phase B at the
   same time.
3. Then loop to phase C, and play all animations in phase C at
   the same time.
4. Etc.

I have an object of named phases, in which each holds an array containing a dynamic number of animations:

```
game.animationPhases = {
    phaseA: [ x.animate(example).finished ],
    phaseB: [ y.animate(example).finished, z.animate(example).finished ],
    phaseC: [] 
}
```

And a function to resolve the animations:

```
async function animatePhasesInSequence(){

    for await (let key of Object.keys(game.animationPhases)) {
    
        let animationsInPhase = game.animationPhases[key];
   
        if ( animationsInPhase.length > 0 ){ await Promise.all(animationsInPhase); }

    }

}
```

The function plays the animations... but it plays them from all phases at the same time.

How might I update the function to achieve the desired sequence of phases?

(*Ideally minimal, and **not** in arrow function format because my brain finds it difficult to read.*)

**Update**: I realized it's not the *function* that's playing the animations... rather, the animations are playing immediately when I add them into game.animationPhases because I'm calling the animate function. I'll try storing their properties separately, then constructing them in an animate function within the animatePhasesInSequence function.

Comment: Are `x.animate(example).finished` and the like `Promise`s? If yes, then maybe it's better if you can restructure them so that they become functions, each returns an unfulfilled `Promise`, e.g. `[function() { return x.animate(example).finished }, ...]`. Then, something like this will do: `for (const phase of Object.values(game.animationPhases)) { await Promise.all(phase.map(function(func) { return func() })) }`.

Comment: Your update is spot on. You might want to [post it as an answer](/help/self-answer)!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:
I realized (and posted an update to my question) that I had been mistakenly calling the animations when I created them, rather than when looping through them as I was intending.

I've since changed the code to store the animation's properties separately, then assemble an animation call from those properties when ready to start the animation. I've used .map() to assign this assembly function to each value in the array of animations passed to Promise.all().

This works as expected:

```
function storeAnimation(animationObject){
    animations[animationObject.phase].push({ element: animationObject.element, animation: animationObject.animation, timing: animationObject.timing });
}

async function animatePhasesInSequence(){
    for await (let key of Object.keys(game.animationPhases)) {
        let animationsInPhase = game.animationPhases[key];
        await Promise.all(animationsInPhase.map(playAnimation));
    }
}

function playAnimation(animationObject){
    return animationObject.element.animate(animationObject.animation,animationObject.timing).finished;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you create an array of keys and then iterate over the array with for loop,
something like this :

```
async function animatePhasesInSequence() {
  const phaseKeys = Object.keys(game.animationPhases);
  for (let i = 0; i < phaseKeys.length; i++) {
    const key = phaseKeys[i];
    const animationsInPhase = game.animationPhases[key];
    if (animationsInPhase.length > 0) {
      await Promise.all(animationsInPhase);
    }
  }
}
```